# How to direct Gnuplot output into a file descriptor (e.g. pipe) directly?

Tags: pipe, output, gnuplot

With Gnuplot it is possible to pipe output into another process, e.g.:

```
set output "| cat >&2"
```

This line redirects the plot output into file descriptor "2".

However, in this case all the Output data goes through `cat`. How can I send the output directly to a file descriptor of my choice?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the `set output` completely from your gnuplot script. Then the output is written to `stdout`, which you can then redirect:

```
gnuplot -e "set terminal pngcairo; plot sin(x)" >&2
```

Comment: This already comes close, but it also writes all the warning and error messages into the file descriptor. For example, when `pngcairo` fails to locate a font, then the resulting warning will also end up in the image data.

Comment: Which shell do you use? In bash `2` is `stderr` so that might be a problem. Here, the following works fine: `gnuplot -e "set terminal pngcairo; plot 1" > foobar.png`. That gives a valid png image, and the warning `Warning: empty y range [1:1], adjusting to [0.99:1.01]` is written to the console. You could also try `gnuplot -e "..." 2>/dev/null 1>&3` to redirect `stdout` to file descriptor `3` and delete `stderr`.

Comment: Will all terminals write their messages to `stderr`? (Is there a Gnuplot standard, which says that all terminals must write their messages to `stderr`?)

Comment: I would expect it since it is a defacto standard for all libraries. Regarding the fitting messages I don't know, but they could be redirected inside the gnuplot script.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid `cat`, you can use

`set output '/dev/fd/2'`

This requires that the anonymous pipe has been opened before. Since `2` is `stderr`, this is usually the case.
The same holds for `/dev/fd/1`, which is `stdout` and seems to be the default, i.e.  `set output '/dev/fd/1'` is the same as `set output`.

But for `/dev/fd/3`, the pipe needs to be setup before. E.g. one needs `3>tmp.ps` on the command line:

`gnuplot -e "set terminal post; set out '/dev/fd/3'; plot sin(x)" 3>tmp.ps`

Otherwise it would result in `line 0: cannot open file; output not changed` `system error: No such file or directory`. Of course `set out 'tmp.ps'` would be even more simple.